# Using a callback function in the formik yup.object() validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, formik, yup

I have a dynamic form, I will not exactly be able to predict the fields and field type so I have been trying this and nothing seems to be working

```
<Formik
            initialValues={{
              // Initialize other fields with empty strings
              ...campaignInfo?.form_fields.reduce((acc, field) => {
                console.log(field.id.includes('email'));
                console.log({ ...acc });
                return { ...acc, [field.id]: '' };
              }, {}),
            }}
            validateOnMount
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            validationSchema={yup.object(() =>{
             const validationSchema = {}
             campaignInfo?.form_fields.forEach((field) => {
      if (field.required) {
        if (field.id.includes('email')) {
          validationSchema[field.id] = yup.string().required('Please enter a valid email address').email();
        } else {
          validationSchema[field.id] = yup.string().required(`Please enter ${field.placeholder}`);
        }
      }
    });

            }}
          >
```

Hope you get the picture and can help

I managed to be able to configure setting the initalValues dynamically, but im stuck on implementing the validation